# Error while merging two tables with reduce

Tags: r

I have list of tables and trying to merge those tables and its working fine if both the tables have data but if there is any table that doesn't have any data its not showing stats .

so i am looking for a solution where if any of the tables doesn't have any data or vice versa it should show stats as 0

```
t1 <- structure(list(` ` = c("CA", "USA","UK", "GER", "Italy","France", "China"),
                     Local = c("38%", "58%","71%", "78%", "91%", "91%", "84%"),
                     Outsider = c("43%", "28%", "29%"," 9%", " 7%", " 4%", " 5%"), 
                     Mixed = c("19%","13%", " 0%", "13%", "1%", "19%", "11%"),
                     N = c("9999", "9999","9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", "9999")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

t2 <- structure(list(` ` = c("CA", "USA","UK", "GER", "Italy","France", "China"),
                     Local = c("71%", "93%","96%", "96%", "96%", "96%", NA),
                     Outsider = c(" 7%", " 4%", " 4%"," 0%", " 0%", " 0%", NA),
                     Mixed = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                     N = c("2800", "2800","2800", "2800", "2800", "2800", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")


colnamess <- c("A1","A2")

df1 <- as.data.frame(table(t1$Mixed))
names(df1) <- c(" ",colnamess[1])



df2 <- as.data.frame(table(t2$Mixed))
names(df2) <- c(" ",colnamess[2])



tl <- list(df1,df2)
t2<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,sort = F), tl)
```

so here if i put anything in Mixed in t2 dataframe then it will work fine

basically tl <- list(df1,df2) is the list of data frames coming from my functions. and i want to merge those.

required output should be

[image]

Comment: Right below creating `df2` you have, `names(df1) <- c(" ",colnamess[2])` - is this accurate or is it supposed to rename `df2`?

Comment: The problem comes not in `Reduce`, but in `as.data.frame(table(t2$Mixed))`. This produces a data frame with 1 column and no rows. Do your original data frames start in a list?

Comment: yes it starts in list

Comment: @jpsmith yes this is accurate

Comment: @potro - so to be clear - if you run your currently posted code, `names(df1)` returns `[1] " "  "A2"` and `names(df2)` returns `[1] "Var1" "Freq"`, and this is correct? Then why do you have `names(df1) <- c(" ",colnamess[1])` just to override it with `names(df1) <- c(" ",colnamess[2])`?

Comment: @jpsmith so basically i am renaming the tables , first column should be blank space " " and and for the second column name i am taking from colnamess

Comment: @potro I understand renaming columns, I am trying to explain there is a high likelihood that you have made a typo. Copy your own code to see what I am saying. You **are not** renaming `df2` **at all**, anywhere in the code you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just use a different approach here, since when you do `as.data.frame(table(t2$Mixed))` you are creating a data frame with a single column and no rows. A nicer approach in tidyverse that does it all in a single pipe would be:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(list(A1 = t1, A2 = t2), .id = 'group') %>%
  count(Mixed, group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'group', values_from = 'n') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Mixed)) %>%
  mutate(across(-Mixed, ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), 0)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Mixed    A1    A2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 " 0%"     1     0
#> 2 "1%"      1     0
#> 3 "11%"     1     0
#> 4 "13%"     2     0
#> 5 "19%"     2     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: i have one more question, lets say df2 is generating as without row and column . but i want to add another column in output t2 with t1 as column name from colnamess "A2" . and the number of rows should be dynamic, because sometimes t1 can have any rows and sometimes i add another t3 and can have rows more than t1. what can be a solution..??

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: @potro I'm not sure I understand your comment properly, but if this solution should work for any number of initial tables with any number of rows. Don't generate `df1` or `df2` at all - just use the starting data frames `t1`, `t2` (and `t3` if it exists) and use the above code.